# Sublime Text 3 fall-back encoding

Tags: sublime-text-3, character-encoding

Any idea how to set default encoding for non-unicode files?

I tried to add to `Preferences/Settings-User`:

```
"default_encoding": "UTF-8",
"fallback_encoding": "Cental European (Windows 1250)",
```

or alternatively:

```
"fallback_encoding": "windows-1250",
```

but neither helps and the Windows-1250 encoded files are still opened as Windows-1252,unless I explicitly use `open with encoding`

Thanks

Comment: "**Central** European (Windows 1250)" instead of **Cental**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to JosefZ's comment I got it working now! The solution is to put into `Preferences/Settings-User:`

```
"default_encoding": "UTF-8",
"fallback_encoding": "Central European (Windows 1250)",
```